# Can anyone recommend a good email client?

Tags: email

I have found that the email client which came with my device (Droid X, stock motoblur email client) is lacking in several areas.  Some of my gripes are

- Limited number of emails shown in the inbox and no way to change this - At any given time, no matter how many emails are in my Exchange inbox, I can only see the most recent 7.
- No option for multiple signatures - with two different business email accounts and a personal email account, I want the option to have different signatures
- Accessing exchange folders - Items are not shown in the folders viewed on the device even though there are items in these folders

I have tried k9mail in the past, but the last few updates seem to have broken it for my device (I reinstalled twice and I still get errors when sending email and new email is not showing up in a timely manner).  So are there any other options available?

Comment: UPDATE: I have been trying the TouchDown client out and it is pretty good.  The price is steep when compared to what is usually paid for an app ($20 after the 30 day trial) but I am willing to pay for something that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using the [TouchDown client](http://www.nitrodesk.com/dk_touchdownFeatures.aspx) for the past month and have been very pleased with how will it works with our Exchange server. Not free, but worth a look imho.

Comment: And they seem to have a free 30 day trial which makes this very tempting.

Comment: Try it out Touchdown is a great app, +1.

Comment: Touchdown works great.

Answer (score 0):

I really like [Enhanced Email](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qs.enhancedemail). It is a paid app (though I got it free from one of the Amazon app of the day promotions), and I have used it as my main client for over a year. I really like all the options and customizations you can set, and it syncs with Exchange as well as standard POP and IMAP protocols.